# A solid reason to use amazon s3 to store assets in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I am using `paperclip` gem and storing the images in the `public` folder, but i saw in many examples that used `s3` to store `assets` like images. why? Also i have read few information saying that when we deploy our app in `heroku` we cannot write or store anything as because it is a `read-only file system`. If so, does heroku provide some services similar to that of the amazon s3.

Looking for more answers so as to get different views and points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that when someone uses your web app, the browser tries to get athe web page the as fast as possible.

If you've only one server rendering html + assets, it's naturally slower than having a dedicated CDN.

Comment: Ok i understand. Does heroku provides any thing similar to amazon s3. If no, then how can we store or write the images to the public folder?

Comment: you can store your files in the public folder, you cannot upload any

Comment: In my web app the user has to upload images at the time of registration.

Comment: you can't, you need to store them in the cloud

Comment: So ultimately i have to go for services like amazon s3. Then what are the alternates to s3?

Comment: `fog`is a useful gem dedicated to this puprose, see the providers it supports: http://fog.io/1.5.0/about/supported_services.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Ryan Bates' Railscast on Uploading to Amazon S3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?autoplay=true):

> In the past, I've done several episodes on file uploads.  But one
> thing I haven't talked about is where that file is stored once it's
> actually uploaded to the server.  Oftentimes, the file is just stored
> in the local file system that runs the Rails application, but there
> can be several disadvantages to this:
>
> - Sometimes that server has limited disk space or bandwidth.
> - Also if you want to make a cluster of Rails servers, that can add some complications.
> - And also, don't forget about the potential security issues of allowing users to upload files to your Rails server.
>
> So there are several reasons why
> you might want to store uploaded files elsewhere...

Amazon S3 simply represents one instance of 'elsewhere'.      :-)